# Groovy Map in Jenkins Pipeline Cutting Off Characters

Tags: dictionary

I'm running into an issue in my Jenkins build pipeline using a groovy script.

Here is part of my groovy script:

```
// Create a map out of our string
di.envVarString = "key1=value1|key2=value2"
def envVars = [:]
envVars = di.envVarString.tokenize("|").collectEntries {
    it.split("=").with {
        [ (it[0]): it[1]]
    }
}
```

Now, this is supposed to create a map [key1:value1, key2:value2]

Running this script on a linux box, or using an online groovy environment in a webbrowser gives me the expected behavior...
However, for some reason when running this groovy script as part of a jenkins pipeline, it breaks up the map into single characters.

for example, I am getting [k:e, k:e] as the map.
What is going on?  I'm not very familiar with groovy, but I thought I had things worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Read up more on split vs tokenize. Split creates a string, where tokenize creates a list.
Updated the inner line from it.split("=") to it.tokenize("=") and that worked.

Posting this so everyone else may know.